# C# redraw canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Good day to you all. The day has arrived when I simply can't find a working answer here and have to resort to asking myself.

First off, I'm quite new to programming, so bear with me here.

What I'm trying to do is make my canvas in wpf redraw some squares that I've generated in random spots in random colors.

The code for making the squares works just fine, but I can't figure out how to make the canvas redraw the 0-2 new squares at the end of the for loop (at the very end, right before the thread.sleep). I tried many suggestions I found online, like canvas.InvalidateVisual and canvas.InvalidateMeasure, but non of them seem to work. The canvas only updates, with all of the newly created squares after it's gone through all the loops.

FYI: I'm aware I commented out the redraw calls. I simply left them there, so you're aware where I attempted to place them.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                newX = rand.Next(4);
                newY = rand.Next(4);
                index = 0;
                writable = true;

                foreach (var Square in size8)
                {
                    if (newX == size8[index].X && newY == size8[index].Y)
                    {
                        writable = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
                }

                if (writable == true)
                {
                    size8.Add(new Square
                    {
                        Usable = true,
                        X = newX,
                        Y = newY
                    });
                }
            }

            index = 0;

            foreach (var Square in size8)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(
                    (byte)rand.Next(0, 255),
                    (byte)rand.Next(0, 255),
                    (byte)rand.Next(0, 255),
                    (byte)rand.Next(0, 255));
                rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(randomColor);
                rect.Width = 128;
                rect.Height = 128;

                Canvas.SetLeft(rect, (512 / 4 * size8[index].X));
                Canvas.SetTop(rect, (512 / 4 * size8[index].Y));

                MainCanvas.Children.Add(rect);

                index++;

            }

            //MainCanvas.InvalidateArrange();
            //MainCanvas.InvalidateMeasure();
            //MainCanvas.InvalidateProperty();
            //MainCanvas.InvalidateVisual();

            Thread.Sleep(200);


        }
```

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at `MVVM` design pattern. In WPF, you normally do not access GUI controls directly.

Comment: Just don't `Sleep()`. Whatever you think you need that for, there are other (better) ways to accomplish it.

Comment: @FlatEric I glanced at it, so basically what you're saying is I should place the code for generating the squares in one class and call the drawing class from it when needed? Makes sense, assuming I got the idea right.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Any suggestions on what these better alternatives are, and why?

Comment: The point of MVVM is to use `DataBinding`. You bind GUI properties to items in the ViewModel and the Binding Engine handles GUI updates automatically. It requires some time to change the way of thinking but it has many benefits.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` blocks the UI thread, causing the application to freeze. `Task.Delay` is more preferable, but Eric is right, shapes and drawings are *not* done like that in WPF: [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No, that depends very much on what you want to do and why. Nothing about that in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Dispatcher helps you with such tasks. This introductory article can be of great help to you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Basically, the idea is that you need to tell the UI thread to refresh the canvas again. Windows and WPF follow a thread-centered model: each window runs on an assigned thread which is responsible for drawing/refreshing it. The WPF API provides with explicit mechanisms to trigger it.

Also, the MSDN documentation on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That's a lot of info. Was hoping for a quick fix, but now I'm gonna have to dig into this problem quite a bit more. Thanks for the answer.

This dispatcher thing confuses me a bit, but will probably figure it out in time.

Comment: Please edit your answer and turn your provided URLs into actual links using the link button, @juampa.